# presenting a modal with a navigation bar causes navigation bar to have 22px too much height

Tags: ios

In an iOS app at work, we have a view controller which presents another as a modal.. Something like:

```
-(void)didTapOnStartButton {
    MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And then the view controller instantiates a navigation controller and puts another view controller on it...  something like:

```
@interface MyViewControler()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *childNav;
@end

@implementation MyViewControler
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    OtherViewController *otherController = [[OtherViewController alloc] init];
    self.childNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:otherController];
    [self.view addSubview:childNav.view];
    childNav.view.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

...  This results in the presented view controller having a navigation bar (as I want), however it's height is wrong.  I experimented a lot with the frame, tried offsetting its Y origin by -22px, but the OtherViewController is a table view controller, and its contents end up being -22px off the screen (covered up by the navigation bar).  So I am not quite sure why this is happening, and how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason you present MyViewController and then add a navigation controller's view to it, rather than presenting the navigation controller in the first place? What is the purpose of MyViewController?

Comment: it makes an api call, has a loading spinner and then pushes on the table view controller with data that was fetched...  It also serves as a delegate to other objects, so it's an important object.  I know my example code looks trivial, but I was just trying to illustrate the bare bones of what's going on...